# How to send string to another window?

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I have two applications, and I need to send "text messages" between them. I have tried PostMessage, but I'm only able to send numbers. I use lParam to carry the message, and if I change it to `string`, I still get only numbers. Is it even possible to send string, and if so, how?

Code below:

```
public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
public static readonly int WM_TEST = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_TEST");

[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
```

Code to send the message:

```
int message = 1234567890;
PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_TEST, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)message);
```

And to receive message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_TEST)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(m.LParam.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

So the question again: how can I send `string` between two apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/BoyCook/5075907) out - particularly `sendWindowsStringMessage`.

Comment: Named pipes, MSMQ, even sockets are just a few of the high level ways to do this, I would avoid low level message pumps if you have control over the implementation in both programs.

Comment: If you marshal it right, you can send strings no problem. I think that's what the Zer0's example does.

Comment: How should I marshal it? With `sendWindowsStringMessage`, I can get the message, but again it's just numbers. Same numbers, whatever string I try to send. But when I restart the receiving app, then those numbers changes. What I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thanks to Zer0 to kick me to the right direction!

Comment: With messages that have payload beyond WPARAM and LPARAM you need to use WM_COPYDATA. You really don't want to be broadcasting though. Why don't you use a more advanced IPC mechanism? Why are you grubbing around with messages?

Comment: @David: Because now that I got it working, it's so damn simple to use for my purposes. One line of code to send message, and nothing special on the "server" side, just listening to wndproc.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

A better way to implement interprocess communication is by using [net sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be later ported to allow *remote* interprocess communication. You basically listen on a specific port on one application and connect to that port from another application, as if it was a remote host on the internet.

Another way to implement interprocess communication is by using [Anonymous Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a windows mechanism for IPC.

Generally, you can check out a lot of different IPC methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

It is not recommended to use [Windows Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this matter, because that's not what they are meant for. WM's are made for the OS to be able to notify a Windowed application about (mostly) UI interactions, even though any application can send WM's to another applications. You have better options for this matter.

Answer (score -1):

RegisterWindowMessage goes through the message queue.  Which is not something you want to do.

Look into OLE.  That is the sanctioned route to take.